# How can I hide tags on a child-category page, if that tag has not been used?

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy, tags, conditional-tags

I have a section of my site where I'm using child-categories and tags to sort content.

I'm have a tertiary navigation for the tags (templates/nav-tags.php):

```
<nav class="side left">
    <ul id="filters">
        <?php
          $tags = get_tags( 
                array( 
                    'hide_empty' => true
                    ) 
                );
            if ($tags) {
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    echo '<li><a id="tag-' 
                        . $tag->slug 
                        .'" href="" title="' 
                        . sprintf( __( "filter post by %s" ), $tag->name ) 
                        . '" ' 
                        . '>' 
                        . $tag->name
                        .'</a></li> ';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is, this lists ALL of the tags, even if `child-category-b` doesn't have any posts tagged in `tag-a`, it will list `tag-a` when on the `child-category-b` page.

I need a way to hide tags/only show tags if they have been used in that child-category.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm working with:
[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge ⤴*</sup>

The `posts` template (templates/posts-easy-steps.php):

```
<div class="feed med no-border" id="sortable-portfolio">

    <?php
        $category = get_the_category();             
            $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'easy_steps',
               'posts_per_page' => 4,
               'category__in' => ($cat),
            );      

        $second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
           while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();

           $titlechars = 45; // Character Limit
           $posttitle = get_the_title();
           $modtitle = substr($posttitle, 0, $titlechars);

           $contentchars = 120; // Character Limit
           $postcontent = get_the_excerpt();
           $modcontent = substr($postcontent, 0, $contentchars);

        echo '<article ';
        echo ' ' . post_class('',false) . '  ';
        echo '>';
    ?>

    <?php

        if( get_field('image') ):

            $attachment_id = get_field('image');
            $size = 'customfeatins'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" /></a>';
    ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/img/content/bf-default.gif" alt="bf-default" width="136" height="90" /></a>' ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        echo '
            <h3><a class="purple" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $modtitle .'</a></h3>
            <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>
            <p>' . $modcontent . '&hellip; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">More &rsaquo;</a></p>

            </article>';
    ?>

    <?php                              
        endwhile;
        endif;
        //wp_reset_postdata(); // to reset the loop
    ?>

</div><!-- [END] feed -->
```

And the `parent-category` and `child-category` template (category-easysteps.php):
*I'm using a function to force `child-categories` to use the `parent-category` template*

```
<div class="container" id="wrap" role="document">

<?php get_template_part('templates/masthead'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('templates/header-top-navbar'); ?>


    <section id="main-content" role="main">

        <div class="column-2 left">

            <h1 class="fs-80 border-bottom salmon">Easy Steps 
            <?php
            if ( is_category() ) {
                $category = get_category( $cat );
                echo ' - <span class="fs-50"> '.$category->cat_name.' </span>';
                } else {
            } ?>
            </h1>

            <?php edit_post_link('edit this entry', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

            <div class="easytags horiz">
            <?php get_template_part('templates/easy-cats'); ?> 
            </div>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/nav', 'tags'); ?> 
            <?php get_template_part('templates/posts-easy-steps'); ?>

        </div><!-- [END] left -->

            <?php if (hchw_sidebar()) : ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/sidebar', 'right'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </section>


</div> <!-- [END] container -->
```

I've been searching for a solution but I'm at a loss...

Comment: Please, [consult the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) whenever you are at loss with a WordPress function. I'm pretty sure you'll be able to answer your own Question.

Comment: My bad, the default for `hide_empty` is true... but what if you explicitly declare it? `get_tags(array('hide_empty'=>true));`

Comment: I had tried that and it still displays the empty tags, I should have explained that in my post.

Comment: Yes, that's what's called "showing research efforts", it avoids RTM situations ;) In a basic test, `get_tags()` doesn't return the empty ones for me. In your `foreach`, print the value of `$tag->count`.

Comment: `$tag->count` shows a count in each, here is a screenshot: [link](http://d.pr/i/n74W) - So it is counting regardless of not being in the current `child-category` (counts if in the `parent-category`)

Comment: Instead of snapshots, you Question needs more code, i.e., what happens previously to `<nav>`? :::: I've just updated the article in the Codex, the last 4 parameters were badly formatted, take a look now if any of that helps. :::: Apart from this, I'm not that good with taxonomies. Hope someone more savvy jumps in. G'luck!

Comment: I appreciate your time and help, brasofilo :) I've edited my post with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, thanks to the help of a co-worker, I now have a solution to this :)

Tertiary navigation for the tags (templates/nav-tags.php):

```
// only load tags from the current page
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'easy_steps',
   'paged' => $paged,
   'category__in' => ($cat),
);
$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );

global $wpdb;
$tags = array();
$terms = array();
foreach ($second_query->posts as $post)
{
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    // get post tags for post
    $taxonomy = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT *
            FROM `hchw_wp2_term_relationships` tr
            INNER JOIN `hchw_wp2_term_taxonomy` tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN `hchw_wp2_terms` t on t.term_id=tt.term_id
            WHERE tt.taxonomy='post_tag' AND tr.object_id=".(int)$post_id
        )
    );
    foreach ($taxonomy as $tag)
    {
        $term = $tag->slug;
        if (!isset($$term))
        {
            // populate tag
            $$term = new stdClass;
            $$term->term_id=$tag->term_id;
            $$term->name=$tag->name;
            $$term->slug=$tag->slug;
            $$term->term_group=$tag->term_group;
            $$term->term_taxonomy_id=$tag->term_taxonomy_id;
            $$term->taxonomy=$tag->taxonomy;
            $$term->description=$tag->description;
            $$term->parent =$tag->parent;
            $$term->count='1';

            $tags[] = $$term;
            $terms[$term] = $counter; // so I know what offset the tag is at in case I need to increase the count
            $counter++;
        }
        else
            $tags[$terms[$term]]->count += 1;
    }
}

if (count($tags) > 0)
{
    foreach ($tags as $tag)
        echo '<li id="tag-' . $tag->slug .'"><a id="tag-' . $tag->slug .'" href="" title="' . sprintf( __( "filter posts by %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></li>';
}
```